# React native flatlist return only one item from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

I'm new with react native.
I'm using a flatlist to render data from firebase (v9).

Everything works well, there isn't any error but, the list show only one item.
After searching on differents topic, I think the problem is from the keyExtractor.
But i don't know how to solve it.

**The Key Extractor from the code :**

```
keyExtractor={item => item.id}
```

**Here is the code :**

```
 const Liste = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "form"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  setUsers([...users, doc.data()] );
});
    }

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
      return(

        <View>
          <View>
            <Text>{`${item.Address}`}</Text>
            <Text>{`${item.Prix}`}</Text>
            <Text>{`${id}`}</Text> 
          </View>
        </View>

      );
     };
  
    const renderLoader = () => {
      return (
        isLoading ?
          <View style={styles.loaderStyle}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#aaa" />
          </View> : null
      );
    };
  
    const loadMoreItem = () => {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
    };
  

   return (
       <View
         <StatusBar backgroundColor="#000" />
      <FlatList
        data={users}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        ListFooterComponent={renderLoader}
        onEndReached={loadMoreItem}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
      />
       </View>
   )}
 
 export default Liste;
```

**Firestore :**

[image]

**The screen of the app :**

[image]

Can you please help me ??
Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Try using `useEffect` hook to fetch data from Firebase. 
Also don't call `setUsers()` inside the loop. Store the values in a local array and update state after the loop is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended best practice is to run side effects like fetch data from server inside `useEffect` hook.

```js
const Liste = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const getUsers = async () => {
    let result = [];
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "form"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      result.push(doc.data());
    });

    setUsers([...result]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text>{`${item.Address}`}</Text>
          <Text>{`${item.Prix}`}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const renderLoader = () => {
    return isLoading ? (
      <View style={styles.loaderStyle}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#aaa" />
      </View>
    ) : null;
  };

  const loadMoreItem = () => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#000" />
      <FlatList
        data={users}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        ListFooterComponent={renderLoader}
        onEndReached={loadMoreItem}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Liste;
```

Comment: Thanks à lot men !! It works perfectly

Comment: Glad to hear that, Anyway, happy coding!